# SQL query to join two tables and get latest data based on ApprovedByLevel

Tags: sql, sql-server

***Data Table***

[image]
.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [RecordNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Data1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Data2] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image]

***Approval Table***

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Approval](
    [RecordNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedByLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedByName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image]

In approval table I store the record No. and the person who is approving the record. 
Many persons approve the same record and finally I would like to show only the Last Approved By Person Level and Name by combining the data table.
***Expecting query to Result***

[image]

Using Ms-SQL Server 2014

> ***Update***

In this

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1c10b03c62b282d096a1f7d7dbfca4b

I want to get the result as

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you want these 2 rows in the expected results?

Comment: In approval table I store the record No. and the person who is approving the record.  Many persons approve the same record and finally I would like to show only the Last Approved By Person Level and Name by combining the data table.

Comment: Last is the same as maximum ApprovedByLevel?

Comment: Try like this `select * from approval as da inner join data as dd on da.record_number = dd.record_number order by da.approved_by_level DESC`  or as your script `SELECT * FOM [dbo].[approval] as da inner join [dbo].[data] as dd on da.[RecordNumber] = dd.[RecordNumber] order by da.[ApprovedBylevel] DESC`

Comment: Its getting all the records getting repeated to 5 rows. Since Approval Table is having 5 entries.  But I would like to get 2 rows result only.  Since Data Table consist 2 rows of data only.

Comment: Which 2 rows? There isn't a date column to get the last. What do you mean by last?

Comment: I think you are under the common delusion, that there is a natural order in which records are stored to a database, and that you can therefore obtain the last record entered, without having an incremental id or an inserted_at datetime column.  The SQL standard has no such provision.  In order to achieve what you want, you will need to add a column to your approvals table: either an incremental primary key (for example with an identity column) or via a datetime.

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock, ApprovedByLevel is the number which decides the Latest entry.

Comment: @forpas, ApprovedByLevel is the number which decides the Last approval.

Comment: @Sixthsense check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` window function to get the `[ApprovedByLevel]` that you want in the results:

```
select d.*, 
  COALESCE(a.[ApprovedByLevel], 0) AS [ApprovedByLevel], 
  a.[ApprovedByName]
from [Data] d left join (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by [RecordNumber] order by [ApprovedByLevel] desc) rn
  from [Approval]
) a
on a.[RecordNumber] = d.[RecordNumber] and a.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=321a54b37e5abfc3bf60b0aa698e57bd).
Results:

```
> RecordNumber | Data1 | Data2 | ApprovedByLevel | ApprovedByName
> -----------: | :---- | :---- | --------------: | :-------------
>         1001 | A     | AA    |               3 | Mr.C          
>         1002 | B     | BB    |               5 | Mr.DD
>         1003 | C     | CC    |               0 |
```

Comment: Just 1 more thing.. Is it possible to replace ApprovedByLevel null to 0? If possible

Comment: @Sixthsense This answer is better as it solves the problem with the unique ID :-)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if that helps, but you could use Join with Top 1 in sub select:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.data D
JOIN     dbo.Approval A
ON       A.ApprovedByLevel =
         (
         SELECT  TOP 1 ApprovedByLevel 
         FROM    Approval 
         WHERE   RecordNumber = D.RecordNumber
         order by ApprovedByLevel desc
         )
```

> Note: You will have problems when there are more records with the same
>   value in approvedlevel. You need a unique ID for the tabel
>   dbo.approval. This should then be used in join condition.

If you have a RecordNumber in dbo.data but not in dbo.Approval, you could use `left outer join`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.data D
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Approval A
ON       A.ApprovedByLevel =
         (
         SELECT  TOP 1 ApprovedByLevel 
         FROM    Approval 
         WHERE   RecordNumber = D.RecordNumber
         order by ApprovedByLevel desc
         )
```

If you need Zero values instead of `NULL` you could use `ISNULL()-Function`:

```
SELECT   D.*, ISNULL(A.ApprovedByLevel,0), A.ApprovedByName
FROM     dbo.data D
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Approval A
ON       A.ApprovedByLevel =
         (
         SELECT  TOP 1 ApprovedByLevel 
         FROM    Approval 
         WHERE   RecordNumber = D.RecordNumber
         order by ApprovedByLevel desc
         )
```

Comment: This works nice. But the problem is if there is 1003 Record Number in Data and there is no record in approval table for 1003. Then I need the result to show 1003 record also but the ApprovedByLevel should be null or zero. Is it possible?

Comment: you could use `left outer join`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Just 1 more thing.. Is it possible to replace ApprovedByLevel null to 0? If possible

Comment: `ISNULL(A.ApprovedByLevel,0)` will give you a Zero if the Value of the column is `NULL` - added to answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add a date column `ApprovingDate` to avoid having problems when there are more records with the same value in ApprovedLevel :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59311/10)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
    [RecordNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Data1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Data2] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)
INSERT INTO dbo.[Data]([RecordNumber],[Data1],[Data2])
VALUES(1001,'A','AA'),(1002,'B','BB')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Approval](
    [RecordNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedByLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedByName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Approval] VALUES(1001,1,'Mr.A'),(1001,2,'Mr.B'),
                            (1002,2,'Mr.AA'),(1001,3,'Mr.C'),
                            (1002,5,'Mr.DD')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select TOP 2 * from Approval as da 
inner join [data] as dd on da.recordnumber = dd.recordnumber 
order by da.approvedbylevel DESC
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.data dt
JOIN     dbo.Approval a
ON       a.ApprovedByLevel =
         (
         SELECT  TOP 1 ApprovedByLevel 
         FROM    Approval 
         WHERE   RecordNumber = dt.RecordNumber
         order by ApprovedByLevel desc
         )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59311/10/0)**:

```
| RecordNumber | Data1 | Data2 | RecordNumber | ApprovedByLevel | ApprovedByName |
|--------------|-------|-------|--------------|-----------------|----------------|
|         1001 |     A |    AA |         1001 |               3 |           Mr.C |
|         1002 |     B |    BB |         1002 |               5 |          Mr.DD |
```

Comment: Query 2, This works nice.  But the problem is if there is 1003 Record Number in Data and there is no record in approval table for 1003.  Then I need the result to show 1003 record also but the ApprovedByLevel should be null or zero.  Is it possible?

Comment: @Sixthsense just insert a record in approval table with 1003 record number

Comment: Hmm.. Yes you are right.  But when no one is approved that record then there will not be any entry in approval table.  I need query to get all records from data table and I just want to know in which stage the record is.. (i.e.) In approval stage.  If there is no record in approval data then I want to see null or 0 for that.